# Prove that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$

Tags: calculus, roots, monotone-functions

> I want to prove that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ where $$f(x):= \sqrt[n]{{x}^{n-1}}$$

---

I proved that $\forall x \in [0,1]$ : $f(x)>x$
and tried to demonstrate $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ starting with: let's suppose $f(a+b)>f(a)+f(b)$  ( to find a contradiction)
but i didnt find any contradiction

any little hint would be appreciated

Comment: What do you get for $a=b=1?$

Comment: Did you copied the question wrong

Comment: This is called the [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)

Answer (score 6):

No, take $n=2$,

$$\sqrt 2\ne 1+1.$$